# How to suppress some compiler some warnings after enable swagger to generate a file containing API documentation

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

After I enable `Generate a file containing API documentation` in my .NET 6 web api project, I got a lot of compiler warnings. Actually, I only need XML comment for all my controllers type or member. But not the rest of the classes.

[image]

How do I disable or suppress the compiler warning?

I do not wish to use pragma directives which clutter the code readability.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved after adding it as below

[image]